Correct Approach to Handling GenAI Answers?
What's the correct approach for answers that have been, or suspected to be, generated via AI? I've flagged as in need of mod intervention and stated suspected AI generated but happy to hear if there is a consistent approach we should take.
Couple of examples from a new user (the phrasing the question back in the answer is a flag for me):
Salesforce - SharePoint integration
How to establish API connection to a Trial Enterprise Edition org?

This one is tricky to deal with still. The two from this user I left in place for the community to decide on. They do have an air of AI about them, but they're not ChatGPT style, that's not to say they're from a different LLM.
If the consensus here on meta is they should be removed I'm happy to do that.
I did remove another new user from the site today who posted 11 answers within an hour or so yesterday, all of which were clearly AI generated. I could have just deleted the questions themselves, but as someone who'd never posted any other answers I didn't expect them to suddenly start posting proper answers, and while it was 11 today it could be 50 tomorrow.
It was possibly a bit harsh of me, but I stand by it :)

LLMs are not trained on Salesforce (or any other specific tech stack), so it tends to hallucinate that it's writing Java, JavaScript, C++, or another popular language. There are some users I've advised to stop using obvious AI-generated content. Using AI is like using a cheat device in a video game. Fun if you're doing it for yourself, not fun in a public society, especially since it can spread false information.
